# Extension restrictions on Multiple File Upload (JInput)?

Tags: fix-my-code, jinput

```
JLoader::register('JFile', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/joomla/filesystem/file.php');

$fields = array('one', 'two', 'three');

foreach ($fields as $field)
{
$file     = $input->files->get($field);
$src      = $file['tmp_name'];
$filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
$dest     = JPATH_BASE . "/screen/" . $filename;

 if ( strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename) ) == 'jpg') {
 if (JFile::upload($src, $dest))
{
    echo "upload successful";
}
}
else {
header("Location: /error.php"); 
}
```

The problem i am facing is that when i use the above code :

1) When i try to upload any non-jpg file, **ELSE Statement** is executed :)

```
else {
header("Location: /error.php"); 
}
```

but when i use this **IF-STATEMENT** instead of the above mentioned one. :

```
if (JFile::upload($src, $dest))
{
    header("Location: /done.php");
}
```

and then when i try to upload any **non-jpg** file, it jumps to **IF-STATEMENT** :

```
if (JFile::upload($src, $dest))
{
    header("Location: /done.php");
}
```

Why is this happening?

Just when i change `echo "upload successful";` to `header("Location: /done.php");`
Why does the event change?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

if ( strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename) ) == 'jpg') {
    if (JFile::upload($src, $dest))
    {
        $app->setHeader('Location', JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_mymodule/done.php');
        // Success
    }
    else 
    {
        $app->setHeader('Location', JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_mymodule/error.php'); 
        // File could not be uploaded
    }   
}
else 
{
    $app->setHeader('Location', JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_mymodule/error.php'); 
    // Incorrect file type. Please select a jpg
}
```

Comment: it gives a blank page! but just when i changed `$app->setHeader('Location', JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_mymodule/done.php');` to `echo "something";` it echo'ed **something** even when i uploaded a **.PNG** FILE (but the **.png** was not uploaded!)

Comment: You keep getting blank pages when things don't work. Please enable error report and set it to *maximum* or *development*. As for the redirect code I provided, did you change the path according to where those 2 files are located? `JUri::root()` defines the root of your Joomla site to change the path after that relative to where ever your files are

Comment: Try this instead and see if it works: `$app->redirect(JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_mymodule/done.php', 'Success');`